# How to initialize empty constructor with nested object?

Tags: typescript

I am having the following problem with my code:
I cannot figure out how to initialize `nestedStudents`. Every time I try to do it, it just tells me that that the object might be undefined.

```
export class StudentDto {
  students: number; 
  nestedStudents: {
    grades: number;
    classes: number;
  }

  constructor(
    props: {
        students?: number;
        nestedStudents?: {
          grades?: number
          classes?: number
        }
    } = {},
  ) {
    this.students = props.students || 0;
    //How can I initialize nestedStudents here?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something similar to your statement for `students`, but replace the `0` with something like this:

```js
  constructor(
    props: {
        students?: number;
        nestedStudents?: {
          grades?: number
          classes?: number
        }
    } = {},
  ) {
    this.students = props.students || 0;
    this.nestedStudents =  || {
        grades: 0, // default value
        classes: 0, // default value
        ...props.nestedStudent, // overwrite with what's given
        // ^ doing `...(undefined)` is fine, it just does nothing
    };
  }
```

Comment: I tried this, but it is giving me the error: type '{ grades?: number | undefined; classes?: number | undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ grades: number; classes: number; }'.
  Types of property 'grades' are incompatible.
    Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Comment: Oh I see, I was basing myself on your constructor parameter's type, let me update my answer.

Comment: Hmmm, latest update says: "Spread types may only be created from object types"

Comment: Huh, I guess TypeScript doesn't like `...(undefined)` even though JS allows it. You could use `...props.nestedStudent!` to trick TS into thinking it isn't `undefined`, or use `...(props.nestedStudent || {})` instead.

Comment: Very odd. VS Code and the compiler is giving me back to what the first error is with trying either of those. Tried to overwrite with !, but still the same error

Comment: Can you update your question with the new code? The error seems quite unexpected.